# Android: Using self-defined metadata

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, metadata

I want to make an Android application which shows questions on the go on the basis of user selection. But I won't use a server, and so the questions have to be bundled with the app. But adding the whole questions would not be a great design, so either SQLite database can be used, or xml metadata can be used. But SQlite bundling I heard makes the app large in size. Is that so? And  could someone explain how to refer to a xml file with self-defined metadata, to create questions on the fly. What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: `SQlite bundling I heard makes the app large in size` ... You heard wrong. Buy a hearing aid.

Comment: Don't blame r2 for his gruffness; it's common and understandable for the underclass http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/culturebox/2013/06/droids_in_star_wars_the_plight_of_the_robotic_underclass.html ...though I'd cross-check your sources like a hockey player

Answer (score 0):

the SQLite DB is on the phone already, I've used it a few times with no big jump in .apk size.

If you are looking for an easy-to-use stored hashmap, try SharedPreferences! Though I wouldn't use it for a heavy solution, the implementation guarantees ACID and is very straightforward. you can make several different hashmaps and name them different things with SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

I declare:

```
private SharedPreferences anchorHash;
```

in onCreate:

```
anchorHash = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.anchor_hash), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

inonPause:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = anchorHash.edit();
    editor.clear();
    for( String s: anchors.keySet()){
//it's a another hashMap I want to write here, but you can do this however you like
        editor.putString(s, anchors.get(s));
    }
    editor.apply(); 
//or commit() if you need to know about the success ( it'll happen )
```